# Logical test in Excel based on the Value in the Two cell

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, logic, formula

I need Excel Expertise support to solve my Excel logic test issue.

I have code in two tables which update the value as 1 and 0 based on the availability, SO in a another table I am updating combination of two letters.

Considering AND Logic need to give True or False in the next table

- 0 0, 0 1 and 1 0      - False
- 1 1 in Both Code - True

[image: Table Detail]

Please get the Below LOOM link to Video Explanation.

https://www.loom.com/share/6903e230f9914940943f61b8f823e066

Overall information

[image]

Comment: Sum two HLOOKUPs, XLOOKUPs, or INDEX/MATCHES, one for the LEFT Character and one for the RIGHT Character, and see if it equals 2 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Multi-Lookup

[image]

```
=LET(lData,P5:T9,mh,B3:D3,md,B5:D9,ah,F3:M3,ad,F5:M9,
        y,TRUE,n,FALSE,e,"",
    fr,@ROW(lData)-1,
MAP(lData,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        mm,INDEX(md,@ROW(r)-fr,XMATCH(LEFT(r,1),mh)),
        am,INDEX(ad,@ROW(r)-fr,XMATCH(RIGHT(r,1),ah)),
    IFERROR(IF(mm+am=2,y,n),e)))))
```

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008,
As One scenario only A, B, C and D Need change to Number like 1, 2, 3, and 4, and rest E, F, G and H need to Keep as its. But for those numbers formula is not working.
are you able to adjust accordingly.

Best regard
Indika

Comment: Hello,
I converted all numbers to text, So everything working Perfect way, Thanks a lot for all support.